# What is this instrument and what is it for?

Tags: avionics, flight-instruments

Can anyone identify this instrument?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [Rocky Mountain Instrument](http://www.rkymtn.com/) micro encoder gauge. The company is now defunkt according to their website.

The [description](http://www.rkymtn.com/EncFeatures.htm) of this instrument says:

> The microENCODER is a mode C altitude encoder with a host of additional features. Using solid-state sensors and processing technology with a powerful microprocessor, the unit combines an altitude encoder with a graphic/digital vertical speed indicator, digital airspeed indicator, sensitive digital altimeter and digital outside air temperature indicator. Magnetic compass heading is available with attachment of the optional compass module.
>
> With this information available to the microprocessor, additional flight information such as true airspeed, altitude alert, density altitude, pressure altitude and true air temperature are available at the touch of a switch. Front panel controls allow the user to select options and enter warning limits to tailor the microENCODER to his aircraft and personal preferences.
>
> The combination of all these features in one quality instrument creates a space-saving and cost-effective instrument that can be used as an encoder and primary instrument for VFR sport fliers or an encoder and backup instrument for IFR pilots.

Comment: Great answer. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, and also thanks to @selectStriker for the link to the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Using the reference provided by Mike Sowsun, it looks like the actual instrument would be a **microEncoder** from [Rocky Mountain Instrument](http://www.rkymtn.com/), which appears to have closed operations in 2011.

**Product Manuals**
http://www.rkymtn.com/Manuals.htm